# Различие ответа в браузере и в приложении

Tags: java, http, webbrowser

Добрый день. Делаю приложение, заменяющее работу с браузером для **HP Service Manager** (без **REST API**).

Ответ на сервере, который я смотрю в окне разработки (Ctrl+ Shift + I) на запрос, отличается от того, который я получаю программно `(InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()))`.

На программные запросы получаю всегда одну и ту же стандартную **HTMLку** с обилием кода на **JavaScript**.

Можно ли такое обойти?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ответ различается потому, что ваш код не выполняет **JavaScript**, а браузер выполняет.

Вы можете либо сами эмулировать полноценный браузер или из кода управлять настоящим браузером используя библиотеку, например [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/).

Либо вы можете проанализировать протокол взаимодействия приложения и сервера и сделать такие же запросы как делает браузер.